# compound sorting

Tags: mysql, sorting

made quick research, seems to be no good solution for my problem.

here is the deal.

imagine table:

```
type|filter1|filter2|filter3|filter4|filter5
3   |1      |0      |1      |1      |0
...
```

type - could of values: 1 or 2 or 3;
filters 1 - 5 - booleans;

the sort i need (from top to bottom descending):

1. type = 3, filter1 = 1;
2. type = 2, filter1 = 1;
3. type = 1, filter1 = 1;
4. type = 3, filter2 = 1;
5. type = 2, filter2 = 1;
6. type = 1, filter2 = 1;
7. type = 2, filter3 = 1 and filter4 = 1;
8. type = 3, filter3 = 1 and filter4 = 1;
9. type = 1, filter3 = 1 and filter4 = 1;
10. type = 2, filter3 = 1 and filter5 = 1;
11. type = 3, filter3 = 1 and filter5 = 1;
12. type = 1, filter3 = 1 and filter5 = 1;
13. type in (3,2), filter4 = 1;
14. type = 1, filter4 = 1;
15. type in (3,2), filter5 = 1;
16. type = 1, filter5 = 1;

so at the top of results would be rows that meet the condition number 1.,
then number 2 and so on.

hope that's clear explanation of the problem.

thanks.

p.s. current working solution is to have bunch of IF's.
...

```
SELECT
IF(@type = 3 and @filter1 = 1, 16
 ,IF(@type=2 and @filter1 = 1, 15
...
)) AS wieght, t.*
FROM table t
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

but that's seems to crying for optimization

Comment: Can you normalize the table?

Comment: @PolishPrince well, that's just an abstract example. in reality, type field is calculated as using FIELD() func, filters 1 through 5 also not stored directly in that table. multiple (5-7) joins are maid.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5)  as mysort,t.* 
from t 
order by mysort, type desc
```

if mysql's concat operator doesn't auto-cast bool to strings of 0/1 you'll need to cast them with an inner expression.

I initially missed your condition for a sort on type in (3,2).  you could use a second level sort similar to your original approach, but since it will involve only the type field it should be less complex.

Answer (score 0):

One idea might just to be to put a trigger on the table that sets a weight field that could then be indexed and used for sorting.  Then the ORDER BY would be very efficient and the ugliness of the weighting would be buried in a trigger independent of any SELECT statements.  The drawback to that would be if the table is updated a lot, then having a trigger on it could slow things down.

Comment: has not worked with triggers before. but have a feeling that will slow things down. on practice that `type` is calculated as FIELD(...). filters 1 to 5 - also set as variables from fields. plus around 4-5 joins on that table are done.

Answer (score 0):

@Elroy Flynn

not sure how this query should work.
here's what i got:

```
select concat(filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5)  as mysort,
t.type, t.filter1, t.filter2, t.filter3, t.filter4, t.filter5 
from complex_sort t 
order by mysort, type desc


mysort|type|filter1|filter2|filter3|filter4|filter5
00110|1|0|0|1|1|0
00110|1|0|0|1|1|0
01000|3|0|1|0|0|0
01000|2|0|1|0|0|0
01000|2|0|1|0|0|0
01000|1|0|1|0|0|0
01001|2|0|1|0|0|1
01001|2|0|1|0|0|1
01001|1|0|1|0|0|1
01010|3|0|1|0|1|0
01110|3|0|1|1|1|0
01111|3|0|1|1|1|1
10000|3|1|0|0|0|0
10000|3|1|0|0|0|0
10000|2|1|0|0|0|0
10001|3|1|0|0|0|1
10010|2|1|0|0|1|0
10100|1|1|0|1|0|0
10110|1|1|0|1|1|0
11000|2|1|1|0|0|0
```